# Schedule exam date and time notification in Firebase Application

Tags: android, firebase, datetime, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I want to implement functionality in the application on which user can schedule their exam on a particular date and time. and I want to generate notification before one day ago, so users will get reminded about their exam. I am using Firebase Database.Should i use Alarm Manager for that? or any background service ? 
I don't have any idea about this. so can anyone help me how to implement this?
any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Since a user schedules their own exam, the entire task can be completed on the device itself. That means that an on-device mechanism like Alarm Manager is probably the easiest way to implement it. Renaud's approach is definitely valid and common, but is more complex since it involves more technologies.

Comment: You are right ! I have to use Alarm Manager for this ! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) together with Cloud Functions.

You would write an HTTPS Cloud Function that would be triggered regularly (e.g. everyday in your case) and that checks, by querying the database, if there are some notifications to be sent, and if it is the case, sends them to the corresponding users.

You would trigger the HTTPS Cloud Function through an external service like https://cron-job.org/en/ or https://www.easycron.com/.

You will find an example of Cloud Function sending Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications in the official samples, here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/fcm-notifications

In this sample, the Cloud Function is triggered by a Realtime Database event (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)) but you can easily changed it to be triggered by an HTTP request (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)), in order to trigger it with the cron online service.

If you are not familiar with Cloud Functions I would suggest that you watch the following official Video Series "Learning Cloud Functions for Firebase" ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) in the doc), and in particular the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" which will show in details the difference between HTTPS triggered functions and Database events triggered ones.

The full doc for Cloud Functions for Firebase is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I learned something new ! Especially for this Cloud Function links ! Appreciated !